# try except structure don't work. user input integers and if not give an error.how to fix?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
print ("please enter values as check([x,y,z])to find min and max")
def check(iterable):
    try:
        (iterable) = int(iterable)

    except:

        print("please Enter number")

    else:
        print("************************")
    it = iter(iterable)
    first = next(it)     # Raises an exception if the input is empty
    minimum = maximum = cumsum = first
    n = 1
    for x in it:
        n += 1
        cumsum += x
        if x < minimum:
            minimum = x
        if x > maximum:
            maximum = x

    return "min:" + str(minimum), "max:" + str(maximum)
```

Comment: Please output the error you are currently getting. I just played around with your code and I found a few bugs, but beyond that I have no idea what it is you are trying to do after that. Please provide more context so we can better help you.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't suggest you take your input as a method like that. Prompt the user to enter a list like this: `1,2,3`. Then from there, convert that in to a list of ints and use that as your structure to perform your logic to obtain the min and max.

Comment: for example: if I enter 10,20,30 out put is "please Enter number
('min:10', 'max:30')".  output is correct but it displays with the wrong print

Comment: Aren't you trying to find the min and max? So your input should just be a list of any numbers. Like: `45,484,2222,2,245345`. Right?

Comment: correct, but using try: except: i'm trying to validate user input only integers, if user input string give an error "please enter number". I'm I doing right on try except structure ?

Comment: I will post an answer to help with the syntax of this.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can break down from what you wrote, the first thing you should be doing is prompting the user to input a list as such:

`1,2,3,4`

So your code should be written like this to accept this input:

```
user_input = input("please enter values as #,#,# to find min and max ")
```

From there, what you want to do is then call your `check` method with user_input:

`check(user_input)`

Inside your try/except for your check method, you must now determine how to convert your string which now looks like this:

```
# pure string
"1,2,3,4"
```

In to this:

```
# list of ints
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So, if you simply do this:

```
# Convert to a list of strings by splitting on comma
iterable = iterable.split(',')
# Iterate over array and convert each element to an int
for i, v in enumerate(iterable):
    iterable[i] = int(iterable[i])
```

To simplify the above, you use what is called a list comprehension, and do this all in one line as such:

```
iterable = [int(x) for x in iterable.split(",")]
```

You will end up getting your list of ints. Now, if you end up providing an input like this:

`1,a,5`

The logic to convert to a list of ints will fail because 'a' is not a int and it will enter your except.

After that, you should be able to continue with the rest of your logic to determine how to get the max and the min.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
def check_user(user_input):
    # code stuff

user_input = input("blah blah")
check_user(user_input)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm doing a school assignment that I must use try: except:. is there any way to fix my code ? do you know the reason why try except structure doesn't work ?

Comment: As I explained in my solution, you place `iterable = [int(x) for x in iterable.split(",")]` inside your try. It will work.

Comment: But, also as I mentioned, there are other bugs in your code which I also highlighted in my solution. Please read my solution *very* carefully. It's all there.

Comment: user_input = input("please enter values as #,#,# to find min and max ")

def check(user_input):
    try:
        iterable = [int(x) for x in iterable.split(",")]
        check(user_input)
    except:

        print("Please enter only numbers")

    else:
        print("....................")

Comment: I don't get any output for this. Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Are you actually calling `check(user_input)`. You have you call your method.  Simply doing